# GoogleMapSDK (GMSMapView) crash with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have added GoogleMap SDK with pods and which is in `Objective-C`.

I am using bridge-header to use in `Swift` project.

In appdelegate I am using this code to provide api key

```
GoogleMapsService.provideAPIKey(kGooglePlacesApiKey)
// where kGooglePlacesApiKey is the key generated on google console.
```

In ViewController I am using below code to add Google map

```
func addGoogleMap()
{
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(51.5074,
                                                      longitude: 0.1278, zoom: 10)
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 157, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 206.1), camera:
        camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.delegate = self
    self.view .addSubview(mapView)
}
```

It always crashes on this line when I try to create object of `GMSMapView`:

```
mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 157, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 206.1), camera:
        camera)
```

And its not giving any error log, it just switches to appdelegate and shows error in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a CGRect with the required frame set to mapview frame

```
var gframe = CGRectMake(0, 157, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 206.1)

        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(gframe, camera:camera)
```